# issue with mysql query (group by)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user),user,ip FROM logins GROUP by ip
```

This is supposed to select unique users from the logins table that have the same ip. For some reason it only returns one row. Users that do not have conflicting ips should not be pulled.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be SELECT DISTINCT(user),ip FROM logins GROUP by ip?

Comment: @Phil Yes, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem? If you tom and peter having the same ip, and jack have a unique ip, what you expect to output

Comment: @Phil I'd expect the rows of tom and peter being returned.

Comment: DISTINCT is a keyword instead of a group function, you should not use it with "group by"

Comment: @Phil Ah I see. I also tried SELECT DISTINCT(user),ip, count(*) as tot FROM logins  HAVING tot>1 which doesn't work either. It's close enough I guess I can do something with php.

Comment: Try my answer below. "having" must be along with "group by"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select user, ip from logins where ip in (
  SELECT ip FROM logins group by ip HAVING COUNT(user) > 1)

Comment: Closest one. select DISTINCT(user), ip from logins where ip in (
SELECT ip FROM logins group by ip HAVING COUNT(user) > 1)
Otherwise it returned same users since they aren't all unique. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, any ideas why I can't user * here -  DISTINCT(user),*. Do I have to type all the column names in?

Comment: Another odd thing is that when I add more columns the DISTINCT command seems to stop working.

Comment: SQL syntax does't allow you to use * with any other column. You either use * only or any other column(s) without *.

Comment: What's the sql when add more columns

Comment: select DISTINCT(user), ip,host,browser,time from logins where ip in (
SELECT ip FROM logins group by ip HAVING COUNT(user) > 1)
What's super weird is that when I add the time column, it starts returning duplicate users, but without it doesn't. Adding host and browser didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       logins1.user user1,
       logins2.user user2,
       logins1.ip
  FROM logins logins1
  JOIN logins logins2
    ON logins2.user > logins1.user
   AND logins2.ip = logins1.ip
;
```

The above will find each pair of distinct `user`s with an `ip` in common, together with that `ip`. (N.B. if more than two users all share an IP, this will return multiple rows for that IP. For example, with four users A/B/C/D, it will return six rows AB/AC/AD/BC/BD/CD. Is that O.K.?)

Comment: Your description matches what I'm looking for, although the code doesn't seem to do that. I had 4 rows (all unique users), two duplicate ips and it only returned one row.

Comment: @domino: Oops, sorry, I had `logins1.user` twice in the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause, when one of them should obviously be `logins2.user`. Try again now?

Comment: Almost works now :). Could I get each user as a separate row without the extra column? For 4 unique users with the same IP it currently returns six rows. (six unique combinations). Which isn't exactly what I want but pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT means "different", if all your user has the same `ip`, then using `GROUP BY ip` will display only one record from your table. Your query is correct!

if you want to display all records but DISTINCT the user. (split off the repeated record, then just remove GROUP BY from the end of your query)